# Arithmetic between 2 files generating a series of new files (Pt 3)

Tags: text-processing, awk, arithmetic

I have a tab separated model input file I would like to vary for an ensemble analysis formatted similar to this

```
cat input.txt
```

```
/*      Precipitation   in      mm      */
10      30      15      20      22      11

###     Species description
***     sp_name LMA     wsg     a_h     Pmass   h_max
abies_lasiocarpa        2       0.5     1       0.001   20
abies_grandis   2.5     0.4     1       0.005   30
larix_occidentalis      1.5     0.3     1       0.003   18
```

I have another tab separated file of multipliers randomly selected from a distribution, with 3 per line such as this

```
cat multipliers.txt
```

```
2        1        3
4        3        2
3        2        3
```

I currently have the workflow set up to handle varying 1 input parameter based off of a 1 column file of multipliers, as shown in the answer to a previous question here ([Arithmetic between 2 files generating a series of new files (Pt 2)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634648/arithmetic-between-2-files-generating-a-series-of-new-files-pt-2)). This approach uses a script called `tst.awk` and is run with the command `awk -f tst.awk input.txt multipliers.txt`. I would like to adapt this script to vary multiple inputs based on one multi-column file of multipliers.

```
cat tst.awk
```

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR {
    if ( tgtFldNr ) {
        lines[++numLines] = $0
    }
    else {
        hdr = hdr $0 ORS
        if ( /^\*\*\*/ ) {      # in case this line is not tab-separated
            split($0,f," ")
            for (i in f) {
                if ( f[i] == "wsg" ) {
                    tgtFldNr = i-1
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    next
}
{
    mult = $1
    out = "file" FNR ".txt"
    printf "%s", hdr > out
    for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++) {
        $0 = lines[lineNr]
        $tgtFldNr *= mult
        print > out
    }
    close(out)
}
```

So, say I wanted to vary the inputs "LMA", "wsg", and "Pmass" based on the 3 columns of multipliers.txt, as opposed to just "wsg" in my current iteration, the outputs would look like the following

```
cat file1.txt
```

(LMA * 2, wsg * 1, Pmass * 3)

```
/*      Precipitation   in      mm      */
10      30      15      20      22      11

###     Species description
***     sp_name LMA     wsg     a_h     Pmass   h_max
abies_lasiocarpa        4       0.5     1       0.003   20
abies_grandis   5       0.4     1       0.015   30
larix_occidentalis      3       0.3     1       0.009   18
```

```
cat file2.txt
```

(LMA * 4, wsg * 3, Pmass * 2)

```
/*      Precipitation   in      mm      */
10      30      15      20      22      11

###     Species description
***     sp_name LMA     wsg     a_h     Pmass   h_max
abies_lasiocarpa        8       1.5     1       0.002   20
abies_grandis   10      1.2     1       0.01    30
larix_occidentalis      6       0.9     1       0.006   18
```

```
cat file3.txt
```

(LMA * 3, wsg * 2, Pmass * 3)

```
/*      Precipitation   in      mm      */
10      30      15      20      22      11

###     Species description
***     sp_name LMA     wsg     a_h     Pmass   h_max
abies_lasiocarpa        6       1       1       0.003   20
abies_grandis   7.5     0.8     1       0.015   30
larix_occidentalis      4.5     0.6     1       0.009   18
```

How would I adapt `tst.awk` to function this way? I have been trying to incorporate `elif` statements into `tst.awk`, but don't think I know enough about what I'm doing to make it function properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
    NR==FNR         { muts[NR]=$0; c+=1; next }
    !hdr            { for(i=1; i<=c; i++) { close("file"i); print >>("file"i) } }
    /\*\*\*/ && !hdr{ hdr=1; next }
hdr {
      for (num in muts) {
          bak=$0; split(muts[num], tmp);
          $2*=tmp[1]; $3*=tmp[2]; $5*=tmp[3];
          close("file"num); print >>("file"num);
          $0=bak
      }
}' multipliers infile
```